# How to get application token to download attachments in an Apiary API?

Tags: python, apiary.io

Using an Apiary backed API (Everhour) to try and download reports, the docs say that I should be able to download attachments using the attachment token, but they dont state how I can figure out an application token itself.

Tried using info like the url info or using inspect element to try and find a link of some wort

```
request = Request('https://api.everhour.com/attachments/????/download')

response_body = urlopen(request).read()

(The question marks are where they say the attachment token should go)

Be able to download the attachment (its a CSV) and then parse it etc.
```